# Laravel 5.2: dimsav Call to a member function translateOrNew() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, translation

I am using
Laravel 5.2
Package dimsav laravel-translatable 6.*

This is my worked controller

```
$about = new About();
        $about->link = $request->link;
        $about->save();

        $localization = $request['localization'];
        //dd($localization);
        // check if locales arabic and english only
        $locales = array_keys($localization);
        foreach ($locales as $locale) {
            if (!in_array($locale, array('en', 'ar'))) {
                Session::flash('message', 'Lang Error');
                return Redirect::back();
            }
        }

        foreach ($localization as $locale => $parameters) {
            $about->translateOrNew($locale)->title = $parameters['title'];
            $about->translateOrNew($locale)->details = $parameters['details'];
        }

        $about->save();
```

but when I try to use mass-assignment

```
$input = $request->all();

        $localization = $input['localization'];
        // check if locales arabic and english only
        $locales = array_keys( $localization );
        foreach ( $locales as $locale ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $locale, array( 'en', 'ar' ) ) ) {
                Session::flash( 'message', 'Lang Error' );

                return Redirect::back();
            }
        }


        foreach ( $localization as $locale => $parameters ) {
            $input->translateOrNew( $locale )->title   = $parameters['title'];
            $input->translateOrNew($locale)->details = $parameters['details'];
        }
dd($input);


        About::create( $input );
```

Got an error

> Call to a member function translateOrNew() on a non-object

any help please what I am doing wrong here.

**Edit :**

My about Model

```
    use Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class About extends Model {
        use Translatable;


        public $translatedAttributes = [ 'title', 'details' ];
        protected $fillable = [ 'link' ];
    }

my abouttranslation model

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AboutTranslation extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'details', 'about_id'];
}
```

Comment: $locales appears to be an array, it's looking for an object

Comment: @Dan White but it accepts the array in the first example, OK do you have any idea how to solve it better way?? regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mass assignment version you are getting an array from using

```
$input = $request->all();
```

You want to use the function `translateOrNew()` on that array which is not working because the array has no function. You have to call the function from somewhere else and save an array with create. I provide a simple example:

```
$input = $request->all();

$localization = $input['localization'];
// check if locales arabic and english only
$locales = array_keys( $localization );
foreach ( $locales as $locale ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $locale, array( 'en', 'ar' ) ) ) {
        Session::flash( 'message', 'Lang Error' );

        return Redirect::back();
    }
}

$input = array();
foreach ( $localization as $locale => $parameters ) {
    $input[About::translateOrNew( $locale )->title] = $parameters['title'];
    $input[About::translateOrNew($locale)->details] = $parameters['details'];
}
About::create( $input );
```

I have to assume many things, since I do not know how the `About` model looks like. Additionally I assume that there is a static method `translateOrNew()` available in this model. Please provide more information about your script, that will improve the answer.

**Update:**

On second thought, why not use this much simpler approach?

```
<?php
$input = $request->all();

$localization = $input['localization'];
// check if locales arabic and english only
$locales = array_keys( $localization );
foreach ( $locales as $locale ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $locale, array( 'en', 'ar' ) ) ) {
        Session::flash( 'message', 'Lang Error' );

        return Redirect::back();
    }
}

$model_about = new About();

$input = array();
foreach ( $localization as $locale => $parameters ) {
    $model_about->translateOrNew($locale)->title = $parameters['title'];
    $model_about->translateOrNew($locale)->details = $parameters['details'];
}
$model_about->save();
```

Just create a model object, use its function and save it afterwards.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: dear I updated my question like you said added the Models any updated on you answer please. I'd like to see how to add the static method translateOrNew().

Comment: @YousefAltaf Updated my question

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to include the following in the model class.
Use `\Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;` in your Model file, which is here: `\App\Article.php`